# How to send keyboard strokes to multiple minimized windows at the same time

Tags: c++

Let's say I have 5 notepad windows minimized. And I have a text file. I want to be able to make my script to be able to read this text file and send the keyboard strokes to all of these programs.

I tried using SendInput() but this only works on foreground windows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HWND hwnd;
    hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, "Untitled - Notepad");
    hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, "Edit", NULL);

    while(!(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)))
    {

                                         if(hwnd != NULL)
                                         {
                                                 cout << "Tick\n";
                                                 PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
                                                 PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_RETURN, 0);
                                                 //SendMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
                                                 //SendMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_RETURN, 0);
                                                 Sleep(1000);
                                         }
                                         else
                                         cout << "Failed, cant find hwnd\n";
                                         Sleep(1000);
    }
    cout << "Complete\n";

    cin.get();
    cin.sync();
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I currently I have, but it does not do what I want it to do. Any help is much appreciated.